# Any ideas why projection would work on the resource level and not on the item?

Tags: python, eve

I have a weird issue where:

Hitting `/api/calculations` I get a list of calculation items with all attributes **except** the `postcard` attribute (which is as I expected) but:

Hitting `/api/calculations/53478f158a866abeff` returns **ALL** calculation attributes **including** `postcard`...!

I was under the impression that `datasource` projections should be applied to both GET levels.  Am I missing something from my configuration...?

That's what's (partly) in my `settings.py`:

```
calculations_schema = {

... some attributes...

  'postcard': {
    'type': 'string'
  },

... more attributess...
}
```

and

```
calculations = {
    'resource_methods': ['GET'],
    'item_methods': ['GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH'],
    'schema': calculations_schema,
    'item_title': 'Calculation',
    'datasource': {
        'projection': {
            'postcard': 0
        },
        'default_sort': [('_updated', -1)]
    }
}
```

and

```
DOMAIN = {
    ... other resources ...
    'calculations': calculations,
    ... more resources ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to also provide a comment when someone downvotes a question, so I know what is wrong with it and potentially improve it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that I was "bitten" by same caching taking place. Eve was not even returning the resource back, but it was rather replying with a [HTTP-304](https://httpstatuses.com/304) and I was just looking at a browser cached version of the previous `calculation`.

What waste of time... :(

But what did we learn today, kids?

Two debugging tips that led me find this out:

- Try your request in an Incognito Window (or another browser) to validate that the problem is generic and does not apply in the specific case you're looking at.
- Check the Network tab of the ChromeDevTools (or the equivalent in another browser) to see the actual HTTP request (with headers and all)